# Контент вылезает за пределы резинового div

Tags: html, css

Есть 4 резиновых `div`. Расположены они по такой схеме:

```
┌────┬────┬────┐
│ w1 │ w2 │ w3 │
├────┴────┴────┤
│      w4      │
└──────────────┘
```

Вот код:

```css
div {
  height: 50%;
  width: 33.3%;
}

div div {
  overflow-y: visible;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#w1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#w2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 33.3%;
}

#w3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 66.5%;
}

#w4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="w1">
  <div id="content1"></div>sometext<input type="text"></div>
<div id="w2">
  <div id="content2"></div>sometext<input type="text"></div>
<div id="w3">
  <div id="content3"></div>sometext<input type="text"></div>
<div id="w4"></div>
```

Javascript периодически получает данные с сервера с помощью AJAX и добавляет их в `#content1`, `#content2` и `#content3`.
Проблема в том, что в `#w1` `#w2` `#w3` не должно быть скроллбаров, так как они уже есть в их `content`, но `content` расширяются и вытесняют `sometext` за пределы `div`. Поставить `max-height: 80%` нельзя, так как `content` при расширении должен прислонить `sometext` к границе и активировать скроллбар. В моём варианте расширение останавливается когда `content` достигает границы сам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопроса нету. Что сделать нужно ?
Если Вы хотите прижать блок с инпутом вниз, Вам нужно сделать `padding-bottom: 50px` у `#w1, #w2, #w3`, и потом на `input[type="text"]` сделать `position: absolute; bottom: 0px;` Тогда Вы его поместите в заранее зарезервированное место и он будет там. Это если говорить о текущей структуре которую я вижу.

Но скорее всего, я не правильно понимаю Ваш вопрос. Покажите на картинке.

Comment: Про свойство bottom я только сейчас узнал, проблема решена.